# ListView не правильно отображает данные при прокрутке после обновления БД

Tags: getview, android, listview, java

Подскажите как можно вставить `getView` в метод `updateView` не кстомизируя SimpleCursorAdapter. Метод `updateView`  работает правильно, но при скролинге картинка выводится не верно, потому нужно использовать  `getView` в методе `updateView`. Подскажите как правильно это сделать или где почитать. Я новичок. Спасибо

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
 ....
 db = new MyDatabase(this);
 getOnListExes();
 db.close();
}
....
    public  void getOnListExes() {  
    onListExesChek = db.getListExes(prog_man, prog_woman, orderBy);         
    sAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
            R.layout.exeslist, onListExesChek, 
            new String[] {"exes_bodypart", "exes_name", "exes_name"},  
            new int[] {R.id.exesPartlist_chek, R.id.exesNamelist_chek,
 R.id.chek_img}) {

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                TextView exesPartlist_chek = 
(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.exesPartlist_chek);
                TextView exesNamelist_chek = 
(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.exesNamelist_chek);
                ImageView imageGender = 
(ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.chek_img);
                return row;
        }
    };
    sAdapter.setViewBinder(new MyViewBinder());
    listExesChek.setAdapter(sAdapter);
   }

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    positionChek = position;
    selectExe_id = Long.toString(id);
    db = new MyDatabase(this);
    onListExesChek = db.getListExes(prog_man, prog_woman, orderBy); 
    onListExesChek.moveToPosition(positionChek);

    if (
onListExesChek.getInt(onListExesChek.getColumnIndex("prog_man_chek")) 
>= Integer.valueOf(prog_man).intValue() &
        onListExesChek.getInt(onListExesChek.getColumnIndex("prog_woman_chek")) 
>= Integer.valueOf(prog_woman).intValue()) {
        if(prog_man.equals("1")) {
            prog_man_chek = new ContentValues();
            prog_man_chek.put("prog_man_chek", "0");    
            int upProg_man_chek = db.setExe(prog_man_chek,
 selectExe_id);
        }
        if(prog_woman.equals("1")) {
            prog_woman_chek = new ContentValues();
            prog_woman_chek.put("prog_woman_chek", "0");
            int upProg_woman_chek = db.setExe(prog_woman_chek,
 selectExe_id);
    } else {
        if(prog_man.equals("1")) {
            prog_man_chek = new ContentValues();
            prog_man_chek.put("prog_man_chek", "1");
            int upProg_man_chek = db.setExe(prog_man_chek,
 selectExe_id); 
        }
        if(prog_woman.equals("1")) {
            prog_woman_chek = new ContentValues();
            prog_woman_chek.put("prog_woman_chek", "1");
            int upProg_woman_chek = db.setExe(prog_woman_chek,
 selectExe_id);
        }
    }
    db.close();
    updateView(position);
}

void updateView(int index){
    db = new MyDatabase(this);
    onListExesChek = db.getListExes(prog_man, prog_woman, orderBy); 
    onListExesChek.moveToPosition(positionChek);
    View v = listExesChek.getChildAt(index - 
            listExesChek.getFirstVisiblePosition());
    if (
    onListExesChek.getInt(onListExesChek.getColumnIndex("prog_man_chek")) 
>= Integer.valueOf(prog_man).intValue() &
    onListExesChek.getInt(onListExesChek.getColumnIndex("prog_woman_chek")) 
>= Integer.valueOf(prog_woman).intValue()
    ) {
        ImageView imageGender = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.chek_img);
        imageGender.setImageResource(R.drawable.check); 
    } else {
        ImageView imageGender = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.chek_img);
        imageGender.setImageResource(R.drawable.notchek);
    }
    db.close();
}

class MyViewBinder implements SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder {  
    public boolean setViewValue (View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.chek_img:
            if (onListExesChek.getInt(onListExesChek.
getColumnIndex("prog_man_chek")) 
>= Integer.valueOf(prog_man).intValue() &
onListExesChek.getInt(onListExesChek.getColumnIndex("prog_woman_chek")) 
>= Integer.valueOf(prog_woman).intValue()
                    ) {
                ((ImageView) view).setImageResource(R.drawable.check);
            } else {
                (
(ImageView) view).setImageResource(R.drawable.notchek);
            }     
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: текст правильно выводится?

Comment: да, текст выводится правильно, кроме картинки.

Comment: Код, конечно, ацкий...

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в вашем коде в том, что вы передаете `SimpleCursorAdapter`'у `Cursor` на вашу БД и тут же в методе `updateView()` "крутите" текущей записью: `onListExesChek.moveToPosition(positionChek)`

`SimpleCursorAdapter` сам управляет записями в вашей БД и постороннее вмешательство ему вредит - от этого у вас и изображение с одного места, а текст (который управляется из адаптера) из другой части оперы.

Запретите `updateView()` перепозиционирование текущей записи и все получится.

Answer (score -1):

Вызывать **getView** не надо, вместо него необходимо вызвать метод адаптера **notifyDataSetChanged**.  Этот метод говорит, что данные адаптера изменились и нужно его перерисовать.

Comment: Неправильно, поскольку `CursorAdapter` сам знает когда изменились данные в БД и сам должен обновляться.

Comment: Я ставил sAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); в методе updateView. Да обновляет, но меняет все картинки списка, на ту которая по условию должна установится в той строке на которую кликаю